# How to refer to female friends in plural form?

Tags: выбор-слова

I have friend (girl) and she's too jealous. I just want to mention her in Russian language that I have another friends  (girls) and she cannot avoid me to be with them, especially when she's not my girlfriend and we're (and we were) not couple.

Now, if I tell her "у меня есть ещё подруги" then she'll not understand, because подруги can be males or females while I want to tell her that I have another friends - girls and she has to accept it as they should do the same.

If I tell her "у меня есть ещё девушки" she'll understand that I mean to female friends and not girlfriends?

Comment: У меня есть знакомые девушки, просто приятельницы.

Comment: If you are talking about real Russian girl then pick words for such case very carefully. And be ready to buy a ticket to North Korea, change name and, probably, gender. Be careful, even if she don't have a pet bear, she could easy become it and tear you to peaces. I know what I am talking about. There are very good answers, so I've just added my advice here ;)

Comment: Подруги can ONLY mean females.

Answer (score 6):

Друзья are "friends", either male or female or both. The sentence is

> У меня есть ещё друзья.(I have got other friends of both gender).

Подруги are female friends.The word doesn't necessarily mean they are all your girls. They can be just friends.

But "девушка" or "моя девушка" shows that the girl is special. She is your girlfriend.

Answer (score 6):

*У меня есть еще друзья* - I have other friends (girls and/or boys)

*У меня есть еще друзья-девушки* - I have other female friends

*У меня есть еще подруги* - I have other female friends (**Beware!** This may sound like they are all your girlfriends)

*У меня есть еще девушки* - I have other girlfriends (You are in relationship with several girls)

Answer (score 2):

Tell her

```
У меня много друзей. Среди них есть девушки.
```

meaning

```
I have many friends. There are females among them.
```

Pretty neutral sentence. She will not react dramatically.